# Makefile error exit with a message

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, gnu-make

Is there any way to output a error message when the error happens.Let's go into details,I want to know whether one file content equal to another or not.If not ,`make` should exit and output a error message.

```
test:
    cmp --silent tmp/test.txt tmp/test_de.txt ||    (error DecryptFile is different from original)
```

When `tmp/test.txt` does not equal to `tmp/test_de.txt`,the output is:

```
cmp --silent tmp/test.txt tmp/test_de.txt | (error DecryptFile is different from original)
/bin/sh: 1: error: not found
makefile:38: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 127
```

> /bin/sh: 1: error: not found

The result isn't what I want.I just want like this kind of error message:

```
makefile:38: *** missing separator. Stop.
```

Comment: Do you want something like this: `cmp --silent tmp/test.txt tmp/test_de.txt ||   echo "error DecryptFile is different from original"` ?

Comment: If so,`make` does not exit with error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `exit`. the `(` and `)` can enclose more than one command:

```
cmp --silent tmp/test.txt tmp/test_de.txt || (echo "DecryptFile is different from original"; exit 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the `error`  refers to the [GNU Make built-in error function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Make-Control-Functions.html#index-error) but then you should write `$(error`....`)` instead of just `(error`....`)` and you cannot use it that way (in a shell command). So you really should use `echo` and `exit` as [answered by tobatamas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44061845/841108). Perhaps you might redirect the `echo` to *stderr* (e.g. `echo message 2>&1` or `echo message > /dev/stderr`)

The `$(error`....`)` builtin could be (and often is) used with GNU make [conditionals](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditionals.html).

Comment: By the way ,what does `echo message > /dev/stderr`  mean? After I redirect to stderr,what can I do using `/dev/stderr`.